# Multiple IF conditions applied to single cell in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I would like to apply the following statements to cell B3
If B1 is left blank then B3 is left blank
If B2 is left blank then B3 returns "Missing B-Day"
If B1 and B2 filled out then B3 returns B2+180
     A                     B
1                         Mike
2 Birthday          1/1/13
3 Birthday +6 Months    6/30/13

Does anybody know how to do it? I have tried with multiple If statements but can seam to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for nested "IF" statements. The first "IF" checks if B1 is blank. If so, blank ("") is returned and the formula exits (even if B2 is also blank).

IF B1 is not blank, the "value if true" part of the formula goes on to check cell B2.

If both B1 and B2 are not blank, you get to the last condition of B2 + 180.

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(B2="","Missing B-Day",B2+180))
```